# RNTN implementation in java

Tags: java, neural-network, opennlp, word2vec, deeplearning4j

I want to implement a Recursive neural tensor network(**RNTN**) in java.

I've used Deeplearning4j for word2vec pipeline to vectorize a corpus of words.

for NLP pipeline I've used Opennlp.( for tokenizing, POStaging and parsing)

Now, I figured out that I need an RNTN for my purpose and I didn't find much support, any references would be helpful. Many libraries are written in R or python or even in Scala and the NLP pipeline most of the people used is stanfordnlp. But I want to do this with Opennlp and java.

After that, I would like to combine the word vectors with neural net and then do the task I want to do something like sentiment analysis.

How can I proceed? Any input will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: You can take a look at  [this](https://github.com/dkmisra/Recursive-Neural-Network-Java/blob/master/RecursiveNetwork/src/recursivenetwork/abstractnetwork/RecursiveTreeNetwork.java) implementation. It uses DL4J for vectorization and implements Binary Tree RNN structure (RNTN).

Comment: I found java a bit intimidating for this task, as the amount of time it is taking to develop a java library is a lot compared to python. I've used Tensorflow to achieve what I wanted. I would suggest using tensorflow is a fast process to get good results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi you can try having a looking at [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) ?

It's a great library for Machine learning in Java.

This link [here](http://deeplearning4j.org/recursiveneuraltensornetwork.html) is deeplearning4j's explanation on implementing RNTNs

[This](https://github.com/fanfannothing/RNTN) is an implementation though I'm not sure how good it is.

Comment: These are the basic material anyone can find just by quick search! and I've used DL4J for word2vec pipeline.